# rails SQLITE code breaks with converted to Heroku Postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have a rails app that uses tagging and sqlite i am trying to deploy as a school assignment. when i deploy to Heroku (it converts to Postgresql) I get an error when trying to run it. It has to do with some differences between SQLITE and POSTGRESQL(from the logs it seems)

There are two tables being joined, tags and tagging which store tags related to posts.

*Rails code:*

```
self.select("name, count(taggings.tag_id) as count")
  .joins(:taggings).group("taggings.tag_id")
```

Here is SQLite generated sql captured from console:

```
Tag Load (0.2ms)  SELECT name, count(taggings.tag_id) as count
FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "taggings"."tag_id" = "tags"."id"
GROUP BY taggings.tag_id
```

Here is the **Heroku log error** based on that statement running under Postgresql:

```
2015-06-20T03:25:00.360433+00:00 app[web.1]: **PG::GroupingError**: ERROR:  column "tags.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
2015-06-20T03:25:00.360435+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT name, count(taggings.tag_id) as count FROM "tags" INN...
2015-06-20T03:25:00.360417+00:00 app[web.1]:   Tag Load (2.5ms)  SELECT name, count(taggings.tag_id) as count FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "taggings"."tag_id" = "tags"."id" GROUP BY taggings.tag_id
```

I am currently experimenting trying to find a solution but could use some help thanks!

I am using postgres 9.3 and rails 4.1

Answer (score 0):

Postgres requires that non-aggregate fields you your `SELECT` clause appear in your `GROUP` clause, so it's unhappy that you're selecting `name` but grouping by `taggings.tag_id`. Try grouping by `name` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the exact same issue and solution here after i posted.  The error pointed to exactly what needed to be done. Include name somewhere in the syntax...I just needed an example.  Here was the final code.
*Tag.select("tags.id, tags.name,count(taggings.tag_id) as count").
    joins(:taggings).group("taggings.tag_id, tags.id, tags.name")*

Answer (score 0):

```
self.select("name, count(taggings.tag_id) as count").joins(:taggings).group("name, taggings.tag_id")
```

easy

Comment: notice a piece of code : group(**"name**, taggings.tag_id")